# user accounts with personal attributes (+ red alerts in Dashboard)

Tags: swift, cloudkit

I am setting up an app in which each user would have a couple of personal infos such as a nickname (string), a list of friends (reference list) and an avatar (reference). I have heard various things about users in Cloudkit such that there are limitations to query among the users, or that it is better to store values in another record, specific to each user. At first I created such a specific record for each user and left the user record intact. But then I've got to store the RecordID of this record in NSUserDefault and it all seem counter intuitive in the end.

Using the first solution (using user record to store everything) I am facing a couple of questions though. Such as

1. How can I simulate other users? Since each user record comes from an Apple iCloud ID, how can I do it? Are there "fake" iCloud ID's that I can use?
2. Why am I receiving those red alerts in the CloudKit Dashboard? What "4 unused" means? and What is the cost (+105%)? [image: CloudKit Dashboard red infos]

I know my question should be more specific, my apologies. I have tried to use Apple's CloudKitAtlas tutorial but it is in ObjC and I only know Swift.
Thank you in advance for any information provided.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed you should not use the user recordType. You are not allowed to query that recordType. If you want more control, then just create an extra record type and ad a CKRefrence to that to the user.

Since you are not allowed to query those fields, the indexes will not be used. The 105% is the percentage of data that your indexes are using compared to the data that is in that recordType